# Can't name the resources folder "Resources" in my Swift package

Tags: swift, swift-package

When I use `resources: [.copy("Resources")]` for my Swift package, the bundle can't be built: "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" (undle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable).

When I rename the folder to something else, the package can be built without issues.

What's wrong with "Resources"?

Comment: What is the directory three?

Comment: Hi, I feel that you need to provide more info. How are you "building" the package? Are you using XCode or Command-In-Line? Can you show us your package's structure? Have you tried using .process instead of .copy? Have you seen the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/bundling-resources-with-a-swift-package)?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `.copy` may trigger code-signing operations depending on the platform. Alternatively, you can use `.process` instead of `.copy` like this:

```swift
resources: [
    .process("Resources"),
]
```

If you use `.process` you also need to update the way how you obtain your resource files:

```swift
// .copy()
let json = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "Resources/user", withExtension: "json")!

// .process()
let user = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "user", withExtension: "json")!
```

From the Apple Developer Documentation:

> If you apply the process rule to a directory’s path, Xcode applies the
> rule recursively to the directory’s contents. If no special processing
> is available for a resource, Xcode copies the resource to the resource
> bundle’s top-level directory.

Comment: Worked for me! Unjammed my build issues.